# Trimming strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a number of strings which are of the format #include "filename.h" I need to pullout the filename.h part from all these strings. For Instance, #include "apple.h" #include "mango.h" #include "Strawberry.h".

```
     getline(Myfile,str1);   //str1 now contains a line from a text file i.e #include "Strawberry.h"
     std::cout <<"\t\t"<<str1.substr(10,(line.length())) <<std::endl;
```

Output:
Strawberry.h"

How do I get rid of the " in the end and just get apple.h or Strawberry.h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but the only problem is that the second argument of your `substr` call is not quite right. `substr` takes as its arguments the starting offset and the length of the substring you want. In your case, you want everything from the 10th and up to the second to last character (the last character is `"`). So you want a string that starts at 10 and ends at `line.size()-(10+1)` (you have to subtract 10 because you are skipping them at first and then one more to not include the trailing `"`).

Try:

```
cout<<x.substr(10,line.size()-11)<<endl;
```

Comment: @Deepak B - I completely disagree.  Hard-coded values are "Bad".  user814628's suggestion might take three lines - but it's the correct approach. You *really* want to "find the string between the quotes".  NOT "the string between positions 10 and len-11". IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4: My assumption was that the  format of the line is fixed and has only one set of quotes with exactly the string `#include ` before it. Trying arbitrary strings would require something more complex than merely finding beginning and ending quotes (there may be more than one set of quotes, quotes may be nested, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like,

```
string::size_type beg = str1.find_first_of("\""); //find first quotation mark
string::size_type end = str1.find_first_of("\"", beg + 1); //find next quotation mark
string result = str1.substr( beg + 1 , end - (beg + 1) ); //return the portion in between
```

EDIT: fixed bug, was adding last quotation mark

Comment: +1 for the approach! This is close, but `size_t` isn't a member of `string` and you're including the closing `"`. See http://ideone.com/8Lrwp for a fix

Comment: Your right, forgot to add +1 to end-beg. And I was thinking of string::size_type.

Answer (score 0):

"substr(10, ...)" arguably isn't the way to do it :)

Personally, I'd recommend considering a "regex" to take everything between the two quote marks, regardless of what the start or end position of either quote mark is:

http://softwareramblings.com/2008/07/regular-expressions-in-c.html

Answer (score 0):

Try line.length()-1 instead of line.length()